# Knockout data-bind not updating on custom event from select binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm having an issue with a `data-bind` updating through a custom event that's called when a `select` element is changed. The idea is that the `select` element changes which updates the `datatype` parameter. Then the change event kicks in which updates `sliderType` which is a boolean and changes to `true` if a specific value is selected. That all works fine, however the `div -data-bind="if: sliderType-` does not update on a change, but it works on the page load.

Is there some way to force the page to recheck bindings?

Here is a fragment of the code to give you an idea of my structure.

#### HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: Items, optionsText: 'type', value: dataType, optionsCaption: 'Choose Data Item...', event: { change: dataTypeChange }"></select>
<div data-bind="if: sliderType">Here is a message. Astonishing.</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
dataTypeChange: function() {this.sliderType = (this.dataType._latestValue.id == 6) ? true : false;
```

#### ko.observable being used:

```
{
    dataItemId: -1,
    name: ko.observable(res.Text),
    dataType: ko.observable(res.DataType),
    dataTypeChange: function() {
        this.sliderType = (this.dataType._latestValue.id == 6) ? true : false;
    },
    sliderType: sliderActive
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part, it would help if the `data-bind` object was an observable

```
{
    dataItemId: -1,
    name: ko.observable(res.Text),
    dataType: ko.observable(res.DataType),
    dataTypeChange: function() {
        this.sliderType = (this.dataType._latestValue.id == 6) ? true : false;
    },
    sliderType: ko.observable(sliderActive)
}
```